# Pentaho Data Integration - Running a transformation with pan.bat

Tags: batch-file, scheduler, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to make a batch file to schedule it on Windows Task Scheduler to run a Pentaho Data Integration transformation with pan.bat

The thing is that I run successfuly each line of the code below, but when I try to run the batch file, it does not fail (according to the log file) but does not reproduces the expected results.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Pentaho\data-integration\"
call Pan.bat /file="C:\Users\username\Desktop\transformation.ktr" /logfile="C:\Users\username\Desktop\log_transformation.txt" /loglevel=Detailed
exit
```

Anyone faced such a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not reproduce the expected results"? What does it produce as result and what do you expect? Please add that in your description as well.

Comment: On execution of the pan.bat, I can see that the transformation was called and started to execute, but a update of a column table (what it is supposed to do) does not happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redirecting the pan.bat output to a text file by using

```
pan.bat >> somefile.txt
```

for standard output and

```
pan.bat 2> some_error.txt
```

for error output. Maybe what you see will get you further.

Details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot. When I execute the pan.bat >> somefile.txt I could see that the name of the file has some ponctuation that impossibilitate its localization and reading by application.